# Allow specific comments on Vite library mode bundle

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, bundling-and-minification

I'm building a components library with React, Typescript, SASS and Vite in Library Mode.

Everything is working pretty well, but I want to add some comments into bundled files to show some info about the lib, like the current package version.

Basically, I want to end with the bundled files including some comments at the beginning of the file:

```
/*
 * Lib version
 * comment
 */

your library code here ...
```

I've tried adding the comments on `index.ts` (the entry file defined in `vite.config.ts`), but it don't appears, even when I set `minify` to false.

I think I have to do it after all minification is done, specially because I want to add the current lib version.

Is there a way to do it?